# Function reference in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to define some steps ( I call them pages ) in an array and each page should have the possibility to call a function on enter.

My page definition is within an array of pages and the nextHandler ( custom method ) sets the current page index and tries to call the defined function. My React class looks ( abbreviated ) like this:

```
var App = React.createClass({
    pageDefinitions: [
        {
            title: "Page 1",
            enterFunction: this.enterPageOne
        }
    ],

    enterPageOne: function() {
        console.log("Something useful here");
    },

    nextHandler: function() {
        var st = this.getState();
        st.currentPageIndex = st.currentPageIndex + 1;
        this.setState(st);
        var page = this.pageDefinitions[this.state.currentPageIndex];
        console.log(typeof page.enterFunction);
        console.log(page.title);
        if ( typeof page.enterFunction === "function") {
            page.enterFunction();
        }
    },

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            currentPageIndex = -1
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>Left out</div>
    }
});
```

While `title` correctly prints out on console, the function is always undefined. How can I provide a function reference in my array?

**Edit:** As @gillesc and @justin-morgan pointed out it is a problem of scope ( this is pageDefinition, not the class )

**Edit 2:** Found solution, I changed `pageDefinitions` to `getPageDefinitions()` like this:

```
getPageDefinitions: funtion() {
    var self = this;
    return [
        {
            title: "Page 1",
            enterFunction: selfenterPageOne
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: `pageDefinitions` is an array of object, so `this` in the first object would reference to the object inside the array and not your main object. So basically `this.enterPageOne` is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not define an array on class level but a function that returns an array:

```
getPageDefinitions: funtion() {
    var self = this;
    return [
        {
            title: "Page 1",
            enterFunction: selfenterPageOne
        }
    ];
}
```

Please note: As a downside , this will create every time a new array when called. This should be considered

Answer (score 1):

`this.enterPageOne` is undefined because `this` isn't bound to what you think it is. Try this:

```
var enterPageOne = function() {
    console.log("Something useful here");
};

var App = React.createClass({
    pageDefinitions: [
        {
            title: "Page 1",
            enterFunction: enterPageOne
        }
    ],
    //...etc.
```

Comment: Now I get an error at line 5 `enterFunction: context.enterPageOne`: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'enterPageOne' of undefined

Comment: @Sascha - I can't believe I just did that. My `context` object would also be undefined at that point. Try it now.

Comment: this works, but the function needs to have access to the state property of the App class, so I just move the problem this way

Comment: @Sascha - That sounds like an unrelated problem, because now we're talking about the context of `enterPageOne` while it's running. I don't know much about React, but if it binds `this` to a context while running `enterPageOne`, and if the state property becomes part of that context, you should be able to access it just fine. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, state seems to be added by the `React.createClass` call, and the initial state can be provided be the `getInitialState` method that I left in the sample code. Moving the method out of the context of   `React.createClass` removes access to the state method. You can have multiple React  classes the do not share the state.

Comment: The issue is that the context was never getting bound in the first place, at least not the way I think you expected. When you write an object literal, the natural assumption is that `this` will refer to the object itself, but it doesn't. For a demonstration of this, run `var x = { a:1, b:this };` and see what `x.b` is. On the other hand, you have plenty of power to manage contexts manually. Why not separate `getInitialState` the way I've separated `enterPageOne`? Then `enterPageOne` can refer to it directly. It just won't be as pretty.

Comment: `getInitialState` is called by React and expected to be on a class

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want a global function outside of `App` component, you can try this. It's not catchy but you can manage it in scope.

```
 nextHandler: function() {
    ...
    var page = this.pageDefinitions[this.state.currentPageIndex];
    //register enterPageOne function into the array
    page.enterFunction = this.enterOnePage;
    console.log(typeof page.enterFunction);
    console.log(page.title);
    if ( typeof page.enterFunction === "function") {
        page.enterFunction();
    }
},
```

Comment: Taking your approach I just could call the function directly, or do I miss a point?